# Facebook graph api get Shared posts content

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a question about the Facebook Graph Api.

I have a script that fetches all the facebook posts of a facebook page. 
The url i use is:

https://graph.facebook.com/#pageId#/posts?fields=full_picture,object_id,message,created_time,permalink_url&access_token=#APPID#|#APPSECRET#;

Now i have this problem, I get all the posts of the feed, but some posts are shared posts on this page. These posts have an own description and the shared post as reference in it. But now i only get the description of the placed post and not the original shared post content.

I'm looking for a way to get the content of the current post and of the shared post.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Check the `attachments` field.

Comment: Thanks ! that was exactly what i needed.